# Detect if there are Ajax jsonp request in progress

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to have a way to detect if there are any ajax jsonp requests in progress.

The standard global handlers

```
$.ajaxSend();
$.ajaxComplete();
```

do not work, as they are not fired for jsonp requests.

Is there any way to do it?